# Beginning C++ Through Game Programming Fourth Edition

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, 32bit-64bit

I purchased Beginning C++ Through Game Programming Fourth Edition by Michael Dawson

and this book doesn't specify whether I need 32 or 64 bit operating system.

Will I experience any code compatibility issues using a 64 bit Windows 10 OS?

This is a 2014 book, and it utilizes Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: I highly doubt it. I would hope anyone who writes a programming book wouldn't write so non-portably that it fails to work on a 64 bit version of the same OS.

Answer (score 2):

Having 64 bit Windows does not mean you can't use 32 bit applications in it. And code compatibility would depend on the flavor of Visual Studio used.

Anyway, VS 2013 does not have different downloads for 32 bit and 64 bit compilers, and has internal options for changing the C++ compiler. 
(Look at [Why is there no 64-bit version of VS2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546402/why-is-there-no-64-bit-version-of-vs2013))

You shouldn't have any problems.

Answer (score 1):

There's no 64-bit version of Visual Studio 2013 anyway, I highly doubt you'll run into a problem.