# Crystal Report Installation

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I am trying to install Crystal report in 64 bit machine for Visual Studio 2013. But it is giving me this error.
I installed Crystal report in 32 bit machine  for Visual Studio 2013 and it is running perfectly fine.
I am adding error screenshot.
Please let me know the solution

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research, there is no Visual Studio 2013 64 bit installation 
[Why is there no 64-bit version of VS2013?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20546402/why-is-there-no-64-bit-version-of-vs2013)

`I downloaded Visual Studio 2013 from DreamSpark but it's the 32-bit version and I couldn't find any 64-bit version. Is there none, and if so why is there no 64-bit version of Visual Studio?`

Based on this, it makes sense that you cannot install the 64 bit version of crystal reports for visual studio if you do not have a 64 bit installation of visual studio.