# Oracle to SQL in SSIS - ETL

Tags: oracle, database-connection, ssis, sql-data-tools

i am trying to get data from oracle database to sql database
i have 3 environments

1. Oracle development server 1
2. SQL development server 2
3. my local host window 8.1 64 bit with SQL data tool 2012

now when i go to add new connection manager under connection manager to connect to oracle server, i am not able to see the oracle connection manager type, i know that i have to install oracle client, but where to install it? in my machine or in the oracle server.

i already downloaded "Microsoft Connectors v2.0 for Oracle and Teradata" and install them in my machine. but still nothing happened, i cant see the connection manager

- AttunitySSISOraAdaptersSetup.msi
- AttunitySSISOraAdaptersSetupX64.msi

in SSIS toolbox i was able to see oracle destination and source component.

i searched the net for a step by step article on how to do this but no luck

please help.

thank you

Comment: Keep in mind that your Visual studio runs on 32 bit. So make sure you have installed the 32 bit version in your local machine for development.

Comment: but my local window is 64-bit

Comment: But your Visual Studio runs on 32 Bit.  - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13603854/visual-studio-2012-64-bit

Comment: how can i check my visual studio run on what? cuz i have windows 8 64-bit

Comment: Visual Studio runs on 32 bit by default. I would say install the 32 bit connectors and see if the Oracle connector shows up in your list.

Comment: can you please provide me with the link to download the connector?

Comment: it doesn't appear in the connection manager. You just add the Attunity Oracle Source or Destination and then configure it. You also need to have the oracle client tools installed. download from oracle